# Multiple colors per vertex

Tags: vertex-colors, vertex-paint

I am able to paint model with Vertex Paint.
Colours are very similar to Normals.
It is possible to have 2 or 3 normals per vertex. (smooth/flat)

Is it possible to assign multiple colours per vertex to use different colours with different faces?

Some how. I do not know how I was able to color model like that

[image]

I do not know how that happened. When ever I try to change colour then affects all three faces like that

[image]

Comment: Vertex colors already work that way.
Each vertex has as many vertex colors as the faces it's a part of.

Comment: Yes. I noticed that sometimes there are multiple colors per vertex. But how do I assign colour to certain vertex/face?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with vertex painting to know, though if I had to guess, I'd suggest to paint each color on the individual face you want to paint with that color. In code it's much easier to set the various vertex colors directly :)

Comment: I added two images. I do not know how to make that. But it seems it is possible. There might be some tool to select faces or Face Paint tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks to me like you have a few overlapping faces. The give-away is that there's some shimmering (called "z-fighting") going on between unpainted white vertices and the yellow verts.

With Vertex Painting you can limit the faces using a Mask. Any unmasked faces will receive no vertex paint instructions.

[image]

This masking mode lets you right click faces to select (mask) them:

- then pick your colors (from the left panel),
- move mouse close to the vertex you want to color
- left click to color.

The [vertex paint page in the manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/materials/special_effects/vertex_paint.html) is worth reading for all the options.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> is great for giving all masked faces the same color instantly. Notice that all masked edges get a faint dotted line around their perimeter.

[image]